# simple html problem frustrating me

Tags: html, css

Why is my gray div only showing half? This is my code :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
<body>
<div style="margin-top: 10px;font-family: helvetica,sans-serif;color: white;background: #212121;" class="round"  >
    <center>
        <h4 style="font-family: Verdana;font-style: italic;">Alumni Activities</h4>
    </center>
    <div style="margin-left: 10px;">
        <p>

            The institution has an alumni association that performs various activities to disseminate knowledge among  students regarding Education, Technology, Trends and Industry. Apart from this, it organizes technical competitions for students to effectively develop their competitive skills and arranges alumni programs that promote effective networks amongst its members.</p>
        <p>
            Events organized by Alumni Association of  are as given below:</p>
        <table align="left" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" width="40">
                        <p>

                            1.</p>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top" width="363">
                        <p>
                            <strong>Event Name: </strong>Alumni Meet 2010</p>
                        <p>
                            <strong>Date of Event: </strong> 27-Feb-2010</p>

                        <p>
                            <strong>Purpose: </strong> Annual General Meeting and Get together</p>
                        <p>
                            <strong>Number of Alumni Present: </strong> 75</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" width="40">
                        <p>
                            2</p>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top" width="363">
                        <p>
                            <strong>Event Name: </strong> Expert Talk</p>

                        <p>
                            <strong>Name of the Alumni: </strong> Mr. Nachiket Patel, Essar Ltd.</p>
                        <p>
                            <strong>Date of Event: </strong> 22-Sep-2009</p>
                        <p>
                            <strong>Purpose: </strong> To enhance the knowledge of students</p>

                    </td>
                </tr>

        </table>
        <p>
            &nbsp;</p>        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Validate your code - http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: @Jason McCreary :- I did and the errors it is showing it is of ckeditor. This table code was generated by ckeditor i simply pasted it in new html page and posted it here ;)

Comment: Either you *did* validate your markup, but pasted invalid markup in your SO question, or you *did not* validate your markup, and said you did.

Comment: As it is, you seem to have an extra div at the end, and also haven't closed off your body and html tags. Is this an accurate copy of your code?

Comment: can you post the code in jsfiddle and make a demo there, so that we can easily fix the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like the classic 'collapsed parent' problem, created by a floated element.  In your case it's the `align=left` attribute on the table.

Removing this attribute is the easiest solution, otherwise there are four CSS solutions, although one of the main two should work for you:

Either add the css `overflow:hidden` to your main div, or add a clear float, e.g. `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` as the last thing inside your main div.

This article explains the theory and the other two possible solutions:

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/10/19/the-mystery-of-css-float-property/

Answer (score 3):

Problem was in messy `align="left"` property in table tag. See normal version: http://www.jsfiddle.net/pereskokov/UMUFt/1/

Answer (score 1):

May I know the round class? I think the div is floated. When you use float div, you need to "clear:both" the div to clear the float element so the other tag won't float too.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are specifying the Transitional DTD level which is the highest level and requires apart of well formed document, that you use only HTML elements winch are accepted for such level, second you have a **div** that is closed but not opened, third remove the **align="left"** attribute of your table:

```
<div style="margin-top: 10px;font-family: helvetica,sans-serif;color: white; background:#212121;"  
       <center>
       <h4 style="font-family: Verdana;font-style: italic;">Title</h4>
       </center>
    <div style="margin-left: 10px; " > 

     <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr><td/>Cell Content</td></tr>
     </table>
</div>
```